# Notify on http server error (Nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I have a website running and today I checked it to find out that the server is returning 502 error. I would rather want to know as soon as possible when it happens again to fix it, so I was thinking about some kind of a solution which will notify me (email) when the server is returning 500 or 502 error. I know that there are some kind of monitoring apps like zabbix or nagios but I think that It would be an overkill because I don't really need that many functions they provide. Is there an easier way to set up those notifications that you would reccomend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a php script that creates an email notification.

Create a custom error page for 500/502 errors and insert your notification script into the code which generates the page.

Use the `error_page` directive to have Nginx serve this page to clients on error instead of the standard 500/502 error page. Disable caching for this page. Now every time a client is served this error page your script will run.

Comment: I was thinking about writing a script and reading nginx error logs but your solutions is much better. Thank you.

Comment: I started out thinking the same but it got messy quick. This seems much cleaner, although you might want to implement some sort of rate limiting for the notifications. I signed up for [Pushover](https://pushover.net) and use them for this kind of thing. They send push notifications to your mobile and have an API, one off fee of about 5 bucks for the app, no monthly or extra charges.